# Use Curl For Finding DataBase Errors?

Tags: curl, database-connection, errors

I have a list of domains in a file say list.txt
I've got a report that many of these domains showing "Database Connection Error"
I want to know all domains that can't connect with db properly. I thought curl could be a useful utility for that, so I try

```
curl -sSf http://`cat list.txt` > /dev/null | grep -I "database connection error"
```

But with that I get whole bunch of other issues, I still get others errors in output, also (the bigger concern) I do not get domain name for which that error outputs.
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the things in loop.

```
for i in `cat list.txt`;
do
if [ "$(curl -sSf http://$i 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'database connection error')" != "" ]
then echo $i
fi
done
```

Comment: got it amigo.. but I get  all sorts of other errors too, which I want to reduce.
Here are examples...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cpec1.co.uk; Name or service not known

Comment: @Sollosa, I edit my answer.